# calculate probability without table

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

my question is related to  normal distribution,namely  as i know in GRE  quantity  section,there could be  question related to normal distribution,but of course we will not have  table,o how can we calculate  probabilities?suppose  such question,mean of  soldiers height is  $170$ cm and std(standard  deviation) $10$,calculate probability that randomly selected  soldiers height is  $190$? $150$? between  $173-184?$of course  we know that  total area of bell curve is $1$ and also   convert given $X$  probability into z score by

$$
Z=\frac{X-\mu}{\sigma}
$$

but without  time table how  could i solve?i dont want to make mistake on exam,i  want to take exam in august.thanks  in advance

Comment: Most no-table tests of this kind I know assume only that you have memorized the more or less famous values for $\sigma$, $2\sigma$, $3\sigma$.

Comment: but for different  $\sigma$ how can you memorize?

Comment: in my example,i know that mean is symmetry,so below or above mean  is 0.5,but   1 std above or below how can i calculate?does it like this:  0.5,0.75,0.9 or?

Comment: @datodatuashvili the link has rotten